# Sorting multiple columns of data read from csv into a Python3 list of lists not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, sorting

I am trying to sort a file with data with data that looks like this:

```
col_a,col_b,col_c
100,100,100
10,0,0
20,30,30
70,20,80
22,88,45
37,18,73
60,72,6
15,18,56
71,67,78
93,48,74
4,93,73
```

I want my sort to order by the first column descending, then the second in descending if there are any ties between the first and second columns, then the third in the same descending manner, if there are still any ties to be handled.

The data should be sorted in this order after the three column sort is complete:

```
100,45,35
87,74,91
71,84,52
70,6,97
70,2,80
5,55,83
5,55,5
```

And this is my program:

```
import csv
import operator

#create an empty list
combined_list = []

#read list of tests from test profile file
with open("data_file.csv") as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    header = next(reader) #there is a header row, which I'm ignoring
    a_row_list = [[int(row[0]),int(row[1]),int(row[2])] for row in reader]
    #add each row read in to the new list
    combined_list.append(a_row_list)

#show its type
print(type(combined_list))

#print records
print("1: Read in")
for row in combined_list:
    print(row)

#sorted method #1
combined_list = sorted(combined_list, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
print("2: First sort")

for row in combined_list:
    print(row)

#sorted method #2
combined_list = sorted(combined_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))

print("3: Second sort")
for row in combined_list:
    print(row)

#sorted method #3
combined_list.sort(key = lambda ele : ele[0],ele[1],ele[2])
print("4: Third sort")
for row in combined_list:
    print(row)
```

However, it doesn't seem to be sorting, no matter which method I try. Here's my output:

```
    $python3 TestSort.py
<class 'list'>
1: Read in
[[100, 45, 35], [5, 55, 5], [5, 55, 83], [70, 2, 80], [70, 6, 97], [87, 74, 91], [71, 84, 52]]
2: First sort
[[100, 45, 35], [5, 55, 5], [5, 55, 83], [70, 2, 80], [70, 6, 97], [87, 74, 91], [71, 84, 52]]
3: Second sort
[[100, 45, 35], [5, 55, 5], [5, 55, 83], [70, 2, 80], [70, 6, 97], [87, 74, 91], [71, 84, 52]]
4: Third sort
[[100, 45, 35], [5, 55, 5], [5, 55, 83], [70, 2, 80], [70, 6, 97], [87, 74, 91], [71, 84, 52]]
```

You can see that all three outputs look like the original, which I assume means the sort didn't work.

Here's some environment information:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.6
BuildVersion:   17G2208
```

I've converted my data to int data type to avoid an alpha sort but I think I'm still missing something. I believe that lists are mutable and therefore assume that a list of lists is also mutable.

Also, how would I sort this by multiple columns:

```
combined_list = sorted(combined_list, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Finally, I'm still learning to be Pythonic in my coding so any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your `combined_list` is three levels deep.  The outer level contains a single list.  A single item list is always sorted no matter how you sort it.  This line reads the whole file an makes a list of lists: `a_row_list = [[int(row[0]),int(row[1]),int(row[2])] for row in reader]`.  This line puts that list inside another list `combined_list.append(a_row_list)`.   Just do `combined_list = [[int(row[0]),int(row[1]),int(row[2])] for row in reader]`.  Get rid of `combined_list = []` and `combined_list.append(a_row_list)`.  Sort by `combined_list.sort(reverse=True)`.

Comment: Thanks Steven - your list of changes worked just fine! And I appreciate you taking the time to explain the problems I was introducing with my code. Do you want to offer it as an answer and I can upvote it.